# copy and rename file in s3, keeping original

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to rename files in an `s3` bucket, but also keep the original. The code below does execute but the files are not copied and renamed. Is it only possible to rename the original and remove it? Thank you :).

**files in s3**

```
123.txt
456.txt
```

**desired**

```
123.txt
456.txt
123.aaa.txt
456.aaa.txt
```

**code:**

```
aws s3 --recursive cp <bucket>/*.txt <bucket>/*.aaa.txt
```

Comment: There's no rename or remove here. It's simply a copy. I would do the copy object by object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash, you could something like this:

```bash
source_bucket="..."
dest_bucket="..."
for item in $(aws s3 ls --recursive "s3://${source_bucket}" | awk '! /\/$/ {print $4}'); do 
  aws s3 cp "s3://${source_bucket}/${item}" "s3://${dest_bucket}/${item}"
  new_item=$(echo "$item" | sed -E 's/(\..+$)/\.aaa\1/')
  aws s3 cp "s3://${source_bucket}/${item}" "s3://${dest_bucket}/${new_item}"
done
```

Output:

```
copy: s3://.../123.txt to s3://.../123.txt
copy: s3://.../123.txt to s3://.../123.aaa.txt
copy: s3://.../456.txt to s3://.../456.txt
copy: s3://.../456.txt to s3://.../456.aaa.txt
```

Comment: Possibly worth piping through `grep -v -E "/$"` to filter out potential folder objects e.g. `archive/`.

Comment: @jarmod ah yes good point, I've fixed the awk pattern